# Is it possible to access an object property when it can have two types (i.e. it has the | operator when declaring the type)?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to access in Angular a property of my object that can have two types.

I have declared an object like so: `parentFolder: FolderNode | File`, but when I'm trying to access `parentFolder.id` the property `id` became red in Webstorm. 
I'm mentioning that `File` doesn't have the `id` property.

My code looks like

```
renameFolder(parentFolder: FolderNode | File, folderName: string): 
                                                    Observable<FolderNode | File> 
{
    return this.http.put<FolderNode | File>(apiVersion + 'files/' + parentFolder.generatedId || parentFolder.id, 
       {
          guid: parentFolder.id || parentFolder.generatedId,
          parent: parentFolder.parent.id || parentFolder.parent,
          name: folderName
       });
  }
```

I feel it must be a better approach than simply use the `[]` like `parentFolder['id']`.

Comment: Object that can _have_ two types or object that can _be_ two types? I suspect the latter and in that case one or both is missing the id field.

Comment: @Silvermind Yes, one is missing the field! Is this absolutely necessary to make typescript work?

Comment: See the docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html, "If we have a value that has a union type, we can only access members that are common to all types in the union.", but you can check if the variable is a folderNode or a File

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks! So this is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write as below

```
(<FolderNode>parentFolder).id || (<File>parentFolder).generatedId,
```